# Uneven CPU load per core

Tags: linux, debian, central-processing-unit

On my Debian server 8. The load on each core is unevenly distributed, as seen in the screenshot, the first 4 core load of about 90 +++% for others it does not exceed 30% -50%. On the server, game servers are running. All started without reference to a specific processor core (ie, must be distributed evenly). At first I thought it was energy saving and lowering / raising CPU frequency, but disable it in the BIOS - did not help. Tell me what could be the problem?

```
uname -a
Linux 3.16.0-4-amd64 # 1 SMP Debian 3.16.36-1 + deb8u2 (2016-10-19) x86_64 GNU / Linux
```

[image: load]

Comment: What CPU do you have? Is it a quad core with HT?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Not likely. More likely to be 12 core with HT, or two 6-cores with HT.

Comment: Understanding the scheduler requires knowing more about the hardware and of the workload. Please provide cores per socket and threads per core with `lscpu` output. Also, install sysstat, run `mpstat -P ALL 1`  and show the Average breakdown per core - we can't really see user vs. system in that screenshot.

Answer (score 4):

**That is perfectly normal.**

Few processes are written to utilize more than one core at a time. When I see a process that uses more than one, it's unusual, either on my multiprocessor/multicore RHEL servers or the Ubuntu and Mint desktops here.

I have *never* seen an htop screen like yours, I think that's as balanced as you could hope for.

And I doubt that you will ever see all those cores nearly perfectly balanced for more than a fraction of a second. :-)

Comment: i seen balance in another my server, CPU the same, but OS is debian 7